# iphone - update UI always on Main Thread?

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I know Apple said all UI-related operations should be carried out on main thread.

So my question is "all UI-related operations" really mean every possible UI-related operaton?

For example, I will addSubview ViewB to ViewA in a separate thread. Should I always use [ViewA performSelectorOnMaintThread:@selector(addSubview:)...... on the separate thread?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.

It will crash otherwise.

Comment: but it is too boring and troublesome, isn't it?

Comment: how about setting the frame or the center or other UI-related property?

Comment: It's all good until your other thread touches the UI. You'll know immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should deal with all about UI in the main-thread.
If you are under MFC, you should be in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Grand Central Dispatch does things in background threads (for example this line:  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), myBlock);`) and no crash at all. And i do a lot of things on `myBlock()`

Comment: so, that means you use main thread for UI, if you use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() :)

Comment: does it? it never frozes the UI, also some long businneses are done after a long while

Comment: yes, try to check with debugger http://gyazo.com/7bd2c7e231715068c3cc8f59a01ffb41