# Problem in creating another thread

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I am using `NSThread` to create new thread that displays images in my application. On the main thread I am working with a table view which is displaying data from XML file, in the same view I am displaying images below. But, displaying images on new thread is not working properly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTheBackgroundJob) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

And the method in question:

```
- (void)startTheBackgroundJob {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    currentLocationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1, img2, nil];
    [currentLocationImageView setAnimationImages:images];
    [currentLocationImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
    [currentLocationImageView setAnimationDuration:5.0];

    [self.view addSubview:currentLocationImageView];
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: It is not of interest, if it is urgent to you. It is not urgent for me. Everyone here does everything without asking for money, maybe just for the rep. But you not even accept answers, so no one will help you.

Comment: @avinash set [currentLocationImageView setAnimationDuration:2.0]; to low .u dont need to use thread for this simple animation .i said in mainthread.and also repeatcount to -1 for repeat forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now that you've started accepting the answers....

Without even looking at your code, the first thing to tell you is, you MUST perform UI activities on main thread... [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164984/iphone-update-ui-always-on-main-thread) for details...

Comment: I am performing UI activities on main thread still the touch is slow. Can any one help me out please??