# How to stop NSRunLoop correctly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsrunloop

I'm using NSRunLoop in my application. Just one statement

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2]];
```

performed in for loop. It is needed to update certain text each two seconds for three times. Everything works fine but when i quit the screen where it runs (and while it is running which is most important ting) and then enter the screen again and then quit it again my app crashes. I presume i have to stop running NSRunLoop if i quit when it's running but i have no idea how to do that. Would you please advice me something?

This is my loop:

```
for (int i = 1;i <= 3;i++)
{
    int result = [self analyzeCards];

   ((UILabel *)[bidLabels objectAtIndex:i]).text = [bidResults objectAtIndex:result];


    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2]]; 

    bidIndexes [i - 1] = result;
}
```

Comment: You should probably show a bit more code than this, Andrey. For example, do you create a new run loop? Can you show that (and the elements that are involved in updating?  a UILabel or?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for modifying your question to include a bit of source code.

I'd recommend against doing the `runUntilDate` thing you have been doing and do this as a detached thread instead ([making sure to actually do the updating the labels -- the user interface -- on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164984/iphone-update-ui-always-on-main-thread)).

The crash itself is most likely happening because the objects in your `bidLabels` array are stale or released or just simply garbage.  Reset that array each time you re-open the window.