# IOS UIWebView Crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

Firstly I'm really new to Obj-C, mostly come from a php javascrript background. My previous apps have all been in Phonegap.  My problem I'm facing is I need to load up a webview but Apple keeps rejecting it because the watchdog timer kicks in on ios 6. So I tried adding the webview to a secondary thread with my spinners on the main thread but then I get this error.

```
Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

Here is my code, if anyone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
[super viewDidLoad];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        NSLog(@"WebView is On Main Thread!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"WebView is not On Main Thread!");
    }
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.example.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    _mywebview.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    _mywebview.opaque=NO;
    [_mywebview loadRequest:requestObj];
    _mywebview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
});
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        NSLog(@"Spinner Start On Main Thread!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Spinner Start not On Main Thread!");
    }
    [_myActivity startAnimating];
});  
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        NSLog(@"Spinner Stop On Main Thread!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Spinner Stop not On Main Thread!");
    }
    [_myActivity stopAnimating];
});        
}    
@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should update UI in main thread, here is the [link][1] in SO.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164984/iphone-update-ui-always-on-main-thread

Comment: I guess removing all your GCD statements would do it, because webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad are asynchronous you can show and remove the loading indicator properly.

Comment: `UIKit` isn't thread-safe i.e. it should be handled only on main thread. Also, all `UIKit` delegate functions get called on the main thread, hence no need to check/make explicit call on main thread from them.

Comment: @Amar Yeah I've read that afterwards but now I'm not sure how else to approach the issue as according to Apple my app hangs on OS 6.1 due to either the watchdog timer or a missing entitlement.

Comment: @shauns2007 Why not move the `UIWebView` load request from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`, so that if this is the root view controller that gets created at application launch, the load time will be reduced. Once the controller is ready for presentation, you load the webview. Worth a try!

Comment: @Amar It does seem faster, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think You use it...

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    NSLog(@"%@",selection);
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];   


 }

 -(void) showAlertforwait{
 UIActivityIndicatorView *activity= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(125, 80, 30, 30)];

    activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;

    alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Process"
                                  message:@"Please Wait ..."
                                 delegate: self
                        cancelButtonTitle: nil
                        otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert addSubview:activity];
    [activity startAnimating];
    [alert show];

  }

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

  [self showAlertforwait];   

  } 
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: 0
                             animated: YES];       
  }  
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"error");
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: 0
                             animated: YES];
   }
```